# Schedule cron job to run on daylight savings time

Tags: cron, dst

I have a requirement to run one or two cron jobs (if one is not enough) for the day light savings every year. The script should be executed every year at below timings. 
1) 2:00 am on second sunday of march.
2) 2:00 am first sunday of november.

I could make it to run every sunday of a month, is there a way to make it work for a specific day like this?

Comment: I would use the "at" command for that:

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97882/why-do-we-need-at-command-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

No, `crontab` has no syntax for this.

What you can do is schedule a job to run every Sunday, and make the invoked command a script that bails out immediately if it's not currently in a daylight saving (not "savings") time transition.

This assumes that the system in question is going to be up and running during the transition. If there's a power failure, or if somebody shuts the system down over the weekend, you'll probably need to make arrangements to run the missed job later. (`anacron` does this, but I haven't used it.)

Answer (score 0):

Daylight saving time transitions occur as time is *approaching* the reference time.

In March, it ticks 1:59:59 to 3:00.  The local clock never actually hits 2:00. So it's not actually possible to schedule for this time.  You can schedule for it to run a second early, but not at the actual moment.

Likewise, in November, the clock goes from 1:59:59 to 1:00.  By the time 2:00 occurs, the transition has been over for an hour.  But if you schedule for 1:59:59, it will run *twice*.

The above (and your question) assumes North American DST rules.  Other time zones transition at different dates and times, or not at all.

See also [the dst tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info).

Comment: For now we are considering Northern American DST only.

Comment: I don't think it will run twice when clocks are turned back. From `man 8 cron`: "... Conversely, if time was adjusted backward, running the same job twice is avoided. ...".

Answer (score 0):

In North America, DST changes occur on 2nd Sunday of March, and 1st Sunday of November. The following cron entries would run on these speficic dates:

## this happens at 1:59 2nd Sunday of March

59 1 8-14 3 0 echo "One minute before setting DST"

## this happens at 1:59 AM 1st Sunday of November

59 1 1-7 11 0 echo "One minute before clearing DST"

Comment: My mistake this will run either on Sunday or day 1-7 of the month. Need to fix this by a test like:

Comment: 59 1 1-7 11 *  test $(date +%u) -eq 0 && echo "One minute before clearing DST"